# How does CollectionViewSource know which item is currently displayed?

Tags: wpf, binding, collectionviewsource

I'm new to WPF and going throw some examples.

One of the example using a list of people and working with the currently displayed item.

The code is following:

```
    People people = (People)this.FindResource("Family");
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(people);
    Person person = (Person)view.CurrentItem;
```

How does `view` know that the current item is the displayed one?

Thank you

Comment: describe what you want

Comment: I just want to find out what happens behind the scene, so the `view` would know which item is current